# ASP.NET Core app CI using VS code and CLI

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

I am using bitbucket private repos as project dependencies with .net core tooling for deploying a asp.net core web api.

I have generated this project using the .net core CLI tools outside Visual Studio 2015/2017 on a Mac system using similar steps as documented in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode)

How do I include the bitbucket private repos as project dependencies for this project and then use the [bitbucket CI pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/continuous-integration-delivery-of-web-apps-from-atlassian-bitbucket/) product for deploying to azure?

I followed a recent [msdn article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core) on CI using asp.net core, but doesn't talk about how to include private or non-globally available nuget dependencies

One way I thought of was by making the private repos as git submodules, but landed up with [issues mentioned here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2375) and [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4124)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and host your own Nuget feed, put your private nuget packages there and update nuget configuration for project to use that feed during package restore. You may read about available options in [Hosting packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) section in nuget documention:

> - [Local feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds): Packages are simply placed on a suitable network file share, ideally using nuget init and nuget add to create a hierarchical folder structure (NuGet 3.3+)
> - [NuGet.Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server): Packages are made available through a local server through HTTP
> - NuGet Gallery: Packages are hosted on an Internet server using the [NuGet Gallery Project](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery#build-and-run-the-gallery-in-arbitrary-number-easy-steps) on GitHub. NuGet Gallery provides user management and additional features such as an extensive web UI that allows searching and exploring packages from within the browser, similar to nuget.org.

Comment: I understand and you are suggesting a Nuget package soln. And it's recommended to use that as the preferred dependency resolution mechanism. But it is possible to use git submodules to manually manage external dependencies as is shown by the heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules That's specifically this question. My query from your suggestion is it possible to use the local feed mechanism for azure CI with bitbucket pipelines? I don't want to host my libs publicly or on the internet NuGet Gallery Project. Basis of why I tried this idea in the first place.